# String Functions in IIS Url Rewrite Module

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, seo, url-rewriting

The **IIS URL Rewrite Module** ships with 3 built-in [functions](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/465/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference/#String_functions):

```
* ToLower - returns the input string converted to lower case.
* UrlEncode - returns the input string converted to URL-encoded format. This function can be used if the substitution URL in rewrite rule contains special characters (for example non-ASCII or URI-unsafe characters).
* UrlDecode - decodes the URL-encoded input string. This function can be used to decode a condition input before matching it against a pattern.
```

The functions can be invoked by using the following syntax:
**{function_name:any_string}**

The question is: can this list be extended by introducing a **Replace** function that's available for changing values within a rewrite rule action or condition?

**Another way to frame the question**: is there any way to do a global replace on a URL coming in using this module?

It seems that you're limited to using regular expressions and back-references to construct strings - i.e. there's no search/replace mechanism to replace ***every*** instance of X with Y in {REQUEST_URI}, ***without*** knowing how many instances there are.

I've had a quick glance at the extensibility [introduced](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/664/using-url-rewrite-module-20/) in the 2.0 RTW and don't see any 'light' means of introducing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have to implement your own provider as shown here:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/804/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module/

Comment: Just an FYI for Developers, this doesn't seem to work if you are Targeting 4.0 Framework, it won't appear in IIS.